# GZipStream does not unzip csv file correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, gzip, gzipstream

For some reason, the file is unzipped incorrectly, the output is a 1KB file, inside there is 1 line of the original file.
The archived file is downloaded from here: https://epss.cyentia.com/epss_scores-current.csv.gz

Program code:

```
public void DownloadExcelCsv(string url)
    {
        string pathFile = path + @"\epss.csv.gz";

        using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
        {
            web.DownloadFile(new Uri(url[i]), pathFile[i]);
        }

        Decompressed(pathFile);
    }

private void Decompressed(string file)
    {
        string decomprssedFile = path + @"\epss.csv";

        using (FileStream sourceFile = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            using (GZipStream gZip = new GZipStream(sourceFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (FileStream targetFile = File.Create(decomprssedFile))
                {        
                    gZip.CopyTo(targetFile);

                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Восстановление файла {0} завершено.\nБыло: {1}, стало: {2}",
                            sourceFile.Name,
                            sourceFile.Length,
                            targetFile.Length));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your code works fine for me. When do you check the content of the output file? When the message box is displayed, the output file is still open and might not yet be flushed. After the call to `Decompressed`, you should see the complete content.